# the confusion about sqlite view query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

when i query a view  use this sql

```
SELECT PRODID ,PRODNAME,PRICE ,storenum FROM V_CHAN_PROD WHERE (SIMPLECODE='6954767410623' OR OUTERCODE = '6954767410623') AND CHANID='10000177'
```

the result is 0

but when I change sql to this

```
SELECT PRODID ,PRODNAME,PRICE ,storenum FROM V_CHAN_PROD WHERE (SIMPLECODE='6954767410623' OR OUTERCODE = '6954767410623') AND CHANID like '10000177'
```

I can get result.
why? what's the difference between  `=` and `like`

Comment: It appears obvious to me, that you are treating **numbers** as if they were **strings**. And the result is actually **correct**: no record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is `CHANID` an integer field?

if so, it should read without quotations

```
CHANID = 10000177
```

The `like` could be evaluating it better against its integer value, where as the string representation isn't an exact match to the integer representation.

The removal of quotes also applies to your other fields if they are integers.

Comment: CHANID a text field. I try the sql  [SELECT PRODID ,PRODNAME,PRICE ,storenum FROM V_CHAN_PROD WHERE (SIMPLECODE='6954767410623' OR OUTERCODE = '6954767410623') AND  cast(CHANID as integer) = '10000177']  and [SELECT PRODID ,PRODNAME,PRICE ,storenum FROM V_CHAN_PROD WHERE (SIMPLECODE='6954767410623' OR OUTERCODE = '6954767410623') AND  cast(CHANID as integer) = 10000177] both work.thank you!